# C# array - "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having a major issue making this work. All I need to do is make my array display.

```
namespace OOP_3
{
    public partial class Add_Child : Form
    {
        public Add_Child()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mother m = new Mother();
            m.MyChildren = new Child[3];

            int ID = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
            string FNAME = txtFname.Text;
            string LName = txtLname.Text;
            DateTime DOB = DateTime.Parse(txtDob.Text);
            //Add children

            label5.Text = m.GetMyChildrenDetails();
            if (addtoarray(m,ID,FNAME,LName,DOB) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("added", "Add Child");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cannot add", "Child add - full");
            }
        }

        public bool addtoarray(Mother m, int ID, string FNAME, string LName,DateTime DOB)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m.MyChildren.Length; i++)
            {
                if (m.MyChildren[i]== null)
                {
                    m.MyChildren[i] = new Child(m); //See comment below
                    m.MyChildren[i].ChildId = ID;
                    m.MyChildren[i].FirstName = FNAME;
                    m.MyChildren[i].LastName = LName;
                    m.MyChildren[i].DateOfBirth = DOB;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

From a code comment: This line destroys everything in the heap and recreate the array causing my to have values that will not show up in my label5.text ive been pondering researching for hours and i think iam either going insane or am just noobie at coding which iam :) please some help would be nice:)....
If needed, I will post my class's and main form up :)

```
public class Mother
{
    //Fields
    private int motherId;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string mobile;
    private Child[] myChildren; //mother "has a" many children

    //props
    public Child[] MyChildren
    {
        get { return myChildren; }
        set { myChildren = value; }
    }

    public string Mobile
    {
        get { return mobile; }
        set { mobile = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public int MotherId
    {
        get { return motherId; }
        set { motherId = value; }
    }

    //constructors

    //methods
    //Get Mother Details
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return motherId + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + mobile;
    }

    //AddChild
    public bool AddChild(Child myChild)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myChildren.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myChildren[i] != null)
            {
                myChildren[i] = myChild;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //GetMyChildrenDetails
    public string GetMyChildrenDetails()
    {
        string msg = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < myChildren.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myChildren[i] != null)
            {
                msg += "\n" + myChildren[i];
            }
        }
        return msg;
    }

public class Child
{
    //fields
    private int childId;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private DateTime dateOfBirth;
    private Mother myMother; //child "has a" mother

    //props
    public Mother MyMother
    {
        get { return myMother; }
        set { myMother = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { dateOfBirth = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public int ChildId
    {
        get { return childId; }
        set { childId = value; }
    }

    //constructors
    //Child cannot be created without a mother
    public Child(Mother myMother)
    {
        this.myMother = myMother;
    }
    //Child cannot be created without a mother
    public Child(Mother myMother, int childId)
    {
        this.myMother = myMother;
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    //methods
    //Get Child Details
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return childId + ",  " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + dateOfBirth;
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void BtnAddChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add_Child child = new Add_Child();
        child.Show();
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create a mother object
        Mother m = new Mother();
        m.MotherId = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
        m.FirstName = txtFname.Text;
        m.LastName = txtLname.Text;
        m.Mobile = txtMobile.Text;
```

Comment: Why does child need to know about mother on create? I think you need to share a lot more code

Comment: i know that alot of code to read most of it unfinished all  want to do is make that line work and the rest should be pretty simple i dont know what i have done wrong and yes my mind jumps to conclusion so it may looked cluster f'd

Comment: Let's look at a very simple case, shall we? One line of code. Why does  `Child c = new Child(m)` need to know about mother? This sounds like bad object oriented design.

Comment: the reason for it is later in my main form i want to display the information about a mother and her child together iam sorry but iam currently learning and still new to programming just doing what my teacher has shown me. or maybe i have misinterpreted rofl my grammar is bad.

Comment: Child c = new Child(m) that is not in my code ?

Comment: You're building a circular structure, are you not? I think this is just poorly designed myself, and that's why it doesn't work. I think the best thing is to ask your teacher for help, even if you're late.

Comment: I think your issue may be this line of code: `msg += "\n" + myChildren[i];` msg is a string, myChildren[i] is a Child object which cannot be added directly to a string....

Answer (score 0):

Giving the new child a reference to its parent object is not the cause of your issue. In summary, you state:

> "to have values that will not show up in my label5.text "

This would indicate that it is either your binding that has an issue, you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or your UI updating mechanism is not working (if you are not using binding). As you haven't stated what you are using for the UI, that is about as much as I can help...

Comment: label5.Text = m.GetMyChildrenDetails()

Comment: @user1778625 In the code that you have posted you are executing that line *before* you call `addtoarray(m,ID,FNAME,LName,DOB)`, you need to call it *after*. Unless there is more code you haven't posted?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, you may use `List` instead of array, because not all mothers have three children. Example code:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mother mother = new Mother {
            FirstName = "M First", LastName = "M Last", Contact = "225632655"
        };

        //Add dependents
        mother.AddChild(new Child{ChildID = 1, FirstName = "Child FirstName 1", LastName = "Child LastName 1"});
        mother.AddChild(new Child{ChildID = 2, FirstName = "Child FirstName 2", LastName = "Child LastName 2"});
        mother.AddChild(new Child{ChildID = 3, FirstName = "Child FirstName 3", LastName = "Child LastName 3"});

        Console.WriteLine(mother);
        //List all the mother dependents
        foreach(Child c in mother.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Mother
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Contact {get; set;}
    private List<Child> _child;
    public Mother()
    {
        _child = new List<Child>();
    }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        _child.Add(child);
    }

    public List<Child> Children
    {
        get { return _child; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", LastName, FirstName, Contact);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public int ChildID {get; set;}

    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", ChildID, LastName, FirstName);
    }
}
```

I hope, this will help.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i have to use arrays and when i use my code all that happens is that message box(which iam using as a testing method say's added but because i have this line m.MyChildren[i] = new Child(m); the array is just continuously recreating which mean that that line is the issue not sure what to do with it. and nothing display's in my label...... i feel brain dead